# How can you access the patch register in a python test?

Tags: python, testing

I have python test which is part of a larger test suite. Inside that test there is a `patch` expression similar to this:

```
def test_my_feature():
   [...]
   with patch("my.module") as mocked_method:
       [...]
       mocked_method.assert_called
```

The problem is that when running this test in isolation the assert_called passes, while running it with the entire suite the test fails. There are a myriad of reasons that the test could fail, but one of the investigations I wanted to conduct is to ensure that no other test patches something and doesn't tear down the patching correctly. And for that I would like to have access to some kind of "patch register" to see at a certain point to check what modules have an active patch.

Is there some kind of way to access such patching registry?